# Lat Long distance calculation

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to get the distance in meters using the below query. But every time I run the query, I get the error below:

> EventException for error: ORA-01428
>   ReasonORA-01428: OracleExecutionException: argument '1.00000000000000000000000000000000000001' is out of range

```
SELECT station,
       name,
       id,
       a.latitude,
       a.longitude,
       h.latitude as a_latitude,
       h.longitude as a_longitude,
        (ACOS(COS(0.0174532925*(90-a.latitude))*COS(0.0174532925*(90-h.latitude))+SIN(0.0174532925*(90-a.latitude))*SIN(0.0174532925*(90-h.latitude))*COS(0.0174532925*(a.longitude- h.longitude)))*6371000)Distance_in_metres

FROM
       address1 h,
       ADDRESSES a
```

Comment: Are you really getting "ORA-01428 ReasonORA-01428: OracleExecutionException" from a MySQL server?

Comment: i am using oracle not mysql server

Comment: So why the MySQL tag? If you tag Oracle instead, you'll get better answers faster!

Comment: What datatypes are your longitude and latitude columns? Perhaps you are getting rounding errors if you are using floating point datatypes instead of number datatypes?

Comment: we are using number datatypes

Comment: Does it help when you replace `0.0174532925` by `ACOS(-1)/180`?

Comment: nope still having same error......

Comment: What gives `COS(0.0174532925*(90-a.latitude))*COS(0.0174532925*(90-h.latitude))+SIN(0.0174532925*(90-a.latitude))*SIN(0.0174532925*(90-h.latitude))*COS(0.0174532925*(a.longitude- h.longitude))`? Maybe make a `ROUND(..., 20)` on it.

Comment: error still there any help plz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already mention ACOS must be [-1,1].
This query may work:

```
SELECT station,
       name,
       id,
       a.latitude,
       a.longitude,
       h.latitude as a_latitude,
       h.longitude as a_longitude,
        ACOS(ROUND(COS(ACOS(-1)/180*(90-a.latitude))*COS(ACOS(-1)/180*(90-h.latitude))+SIN(ACOS(-1)/180*(90-a.latitude))*SIN(ACOS(-1)/180*(90-h.latitude))*COS(ACOS(-1)/180*(a.longitude-h.longitude)), 20)) * 6371000 as Distance_in_metres

FROM
       address1 h,
       ADDRESSES a
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably you has a problem about ACOS function.

EX: If you want to use acos function like this; ACOS(x)

> The value of x should be in the range [-1,1].

You can read more information in this [ORACLE/ACOS](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26505_01/html/816-5172/acos-3m.html)  article.